# PHP times out and PHPmyadmin crashes on query with NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in a database. Table1 stores the users and Table2 stores data generated by the users.

Due to an error some users from Table1, don't have any data in Table2. I would like to notify these users.

I am trying this in several ways using MySQL. But nothing works, because PHPmyAdmin freezes or PHP times out. That's maybe because the first table contains 28.000 rows and the second one contains 80.000 rows. I just need the last 5 days.

**Trial nr 1**

```
SELECT gebruikers.g_id
FROM gebruikers LEFT JOIN objecten ON objecten.o_g_id=gebruikers.g_id
WHERE objecten.o_g_id IS NULL
```

**EXPLAIN SELECT**

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  gebruikers  index   NULL    PRIMARY     4   NULL    25227   Using index
1   SIMPLE  objecten    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    81002   Using where; Not ex
```

**Trial nr 2**

```
SELECT g_id FROM gebruikers
WHERE g_id NOT IN(SELECT o_g_id FROM objecten WHERE o_startdatum <= NOW() AND o_startdatum >=NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 80,000 rows is a very small amount of data for MySQL to handle and it shouldn't be hanging up on this at all, unless it's running on a low end server. What type of field is o_startdatum? Is it DATE or DATETIME? If it's a date, do you have an index defined on this field? If it's a datetime - it may be better to create a DATE column (with just the date portion of this field) and index it. Also, how many results do you expect this to return? Maybe phpMyAdmin is choking up on outputting the data.

Comment: Please include the results of the explain query, `EXPLAIN SELECT gebruikers.g_id...`

Comment: @ColinMorelli I am expecting about 100 results. If there is a date limiter in the first query it should be less. It's a DATE field and it's not indexed. I need this query for now just one time. Normally nothing is done with startdatum.

Comment: @mat Yeah, definitely let us take a look at the `EXPLAIN` as mentioned by Igor. And also post the output of `DESCRIBE` on both of the tables.

Comment: Okay will update the post!

Comment: try : `SELECT 
    gebruikers.g_id
FROM
    gebruikers
        LEFT JOIN
    objecten ON objecten.o_g_id = gebruikers.g_id
WHERE
    objecten.o_g_id IS NULL
        and o_startdatum <= NOW()
        AND o_startdatum >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY);`

Comment: @SparKot Ty, i tried this, but it returns 0 results, while I am absolutely sure there are about 100. When i change o_startdatum (date of the row in objecten) to g_startdatum (date of the row in gebruikers). It hangs again.

Comment: run this `SELECT 
    gebruikers.g_id, objecten.o_startdatum
FROM
    gebruikers
        LEFT JOIN
    objecten ON objecten.o_g_id = gebruikers.g_id
WHERE
    objecten.o_g_id IS NULL
order by objecten.o_startdatum DESC;` and tell how many you see within date range?

Comment: No I am wrong, it doesn't hang with that query, it just took 30 seconds.. And yes, it's an high end server.. :( @SparKot if you answer it, i can accept it. Ty!

Comment: @mat Is it getting you what you need?

Comment: you should still add a key on `o_startdatum`, `o_g_id` and `g_id`

Comment: @ColinMorelli Sort off, still times out most of the times..

Comment: @dualed What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @mat in phpmyadmin in the structure view of the table, on each of the mentioned columns hover over "more" then select "add index". Do this for each column individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query to get required records:

```
SELECT 
    gebruikers.g_id
FROM
    gebruikers
        LEFT JOIN
    objecten ON objecten.o_g_id = gebruikers.g_id
WHERE
    objecten.o_g_id IS NULL
        and o_startdatum <= NOW()
        AND o_startdatum >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Trial nr 1" is fine if second table having null values but it might be field value empty instead of null so you should use or clause objecten.o_g_id = ''.
The final query would be:
 SELECT gebruikers.g_id FROM gebruikers LEFT JOIN objecten ON objecten.o_g_id=gebruikers.g_id WHERE (objecten.o_g_id IS NULL) or (trim(objecten.o_g_id) ='')

Comment: Actually, this would not get what the OP wants.